# Проблема с отображением шрифта на Ubuntu 18.04 и линуксоидных системах в целом

Tags: linux, ubuntu, шрифты

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что текст плывет как на изображении.

[image: Вот что происходит с шрифтом]

А вот характеристики

```
    OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS x86_64
    Host: SQ45/Q70C/P200 04SO
    Kernel: 4.18.0-16-generic
    Packages: 1637
    Shell: bash 4.4.19
    Resolution: 1280x800
    DE: GNOME 3.28.3
    WM: GNOME Shell
    WM Theme: Adwaita
    Theme: Ambiance [GTK2/3]
    Icons: Ubuntu-mono-dark [GTK2/3]
    Terminal: gnome-terminal
    CPU: Intel Pentium Dual T2390 (2) @
    GPU: AMD Radeon Xpress 1250
    Memory: 1049Mib /1740Mib
```

Есть ли фикс для этого, или же мое железо уже просто напросто перестало тянуть шрифты?

P.s. В браузере, к примеру работает все нормально, как и в консоли. Такая же проблема сохранялась и при переустановке системы. В частности, ставил Kali с такой же проблемой и во второй раз ставлю Ubuntu. При установке на этот же самый комп винды, ничего подобного не происходит. XFCe Работает хорошо, без проблем с шрифтом.
P.s.s. Сразу извиняюсь, если задал вопрос не туда.

Comment: `ubuntu-drivers list` чё-нить интересное выдаёт?

Comment: Если быть точным, вообще ничего не выдает @donRumata

Comment: Я конечно не телепат, по этому могу предложить только поставить систему с другой DE. Учитывая что у вас меньше 2 гб памяти, то гном вам даже по официально заявленным системным требованиям не подходит. Советую Xubuntu или Lubuntu.

Comment: Кстати да, поддержу @BeastWinterwolf. Попробуй "крысу".

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, Попробовал поставить, проблема исчезла. Но, так или иначе, мне с gnome для этой машины распрощаться уже стоит?

Comment: @gdl68 Я не могу дать ответ на этот вопрос, потому что точная причина проблемы не известна. Если гном работает на вейланде, то нужно переключаться на иксы. Если нет, то пробовать другие видео-драйверы или режимы композитного менеджера.

Comment: Это проблема с драйверами видеокарты. Основная причина такого бага в том что видеокарта старая, свободные драйвера для нее не обновляют, решение не факт что есть, но может быть поможет смена DDX драйвера на Glammor (2d ускорение через OpenGL): гугли ключевые слова: `AccelMethod Glammor r300 KMS'. Возможно есть еще один вариант - использовать GNOME Flashback (metacity) https://www.debugpoint.com/2018/05/how-to-install-classic-gnome-flashback-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

Comment: У меня такая проблема была когда у видеокарты чип отошёл, простой прогрев помог.